# When would you ever use a range not in the context of an array

Tags: concepts

I'm constantly trying to acquaint myself with different programming concepts, and I recently looked deeper into ranges.

In Haskell a range is basically a literal that expand to some kind of array.

In Ruby (and Python I guess) it is a completely different type.

My question: What are use cases for *ranges* except iterating over them like an array?

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: In Python 2 a range generates a list of numbers but in Python 3 a range is a generator that provides sequential numbers. The python, and several other languages, concept that is equivalent to what you are asking for is a __slice__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range`s are mathematical objects that far predate programming and arrays. What you can do with a `Range` is check whether or not a value lies within a `Range`.

Iterating over a `Range` is *not* the primary use case; in fact, for a lot of `Range`s, it isn't even possible. E.g. for a `Range` of real numbers, you cannot iterate over it because there is no such thing as as the "next real number": whatever possible real number you pick as "the next one", there are still infinitely many real numbers between the current and the "next".

In Ruby, the `Range` protocol is split in two: membership checking and iterating. Objects that are used as endpoints in `Range`s **MUST** implement the membership checking portion of the protocol and **MAY** additionally implement the iteration part of the protocol.

The membership part of the protocol is simple: both the start and the end object must respond to the `<=>` message (the standard combined comparison method which returns `-1`, `0`, `1`, or `nil` for objects that are less than, equal, greater than, or incomparable). For the iteration part, the start object also needs to respond to the `succ` message (and the object it returns needs to respond to `succ` and so on …).

It is perfectly possible in Ruby to, for example, construct the following `Range` of `Rational` numbers:

```
r = 1r..10r
```

I can check membership:

```
r.cover?(5r) #=> true
```

But not iterate:

```
r.to_a
# TypeError: can't iterate from Rational
```